# MariaDB ColumnStore Questions

Tags: mariadb, mariasql, mariadb-connect-engine

I have question regarding MariaDB ColumnStore:-

1. Is this free, can use in production system?
2. Is this the extension of Mariadb (prerequisite is MariaDB) or we can install this alone?
3. Can install in single machine in Production, give better performance in terms of the column stores?
4. Does it support all functionality of MariaDB, I mean directly migration from MariaDB to MariaDB columnstore is possible?
5. Does it support procedure/functions also because I have used vectorwise actian columnar DB and its not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB ColumnStore is a GPLv2 storage engine that enables columnar storage of data. Currently ColumnStore is distributed in a separate package ([found here](https://mariadb.com/downloads/mariadb-ax)) that has all MariaDB functionality it was built with.

The latest ColumnStore has the same features as MariaDB 10.2 plus the `COLUMNSTORE` storage engine. There are also a small set of additional functions that ColumnStore implements (e.g. [some extra window functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/columnstore-window-functions/)).

For analytical queries, ColumnStore tables are almost always faster but they are not suited for OLTP workloads. You can have InnoDB and ColumnStore tables in the same database and even do cross-engine joins.

Stored procedures are supported in the same manner as they are in a normal MariaDB installation. [The ColumnStore documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/columnstore-sql-structure-and-commands/) has a list of features that it supports in addition to the base MariaDB functionality.

Answer (score 0):

(Caveat:  My knowledge of ColumnStore is limited, so these answers are suspect. 
 The Question is 22 days old, so I feel the Question deserves some Answer.)

1. Yes?  The manual makes it clear what parts of MariaDB require money to change hands.
2. ColumnStore used to be available as InfiniDB.  But after MariaDB took it on, it became integrated with MariaDB.
3. (Unclear question)  Columnstore has a niche market.  It is not practical to attempt answering how its performance compares to non-column-store engines.  Perhaps with a discussion of the application we can discuss this further.
4. All(?) MariaDB functionality is available.
5. I don't know anything about "vectorwise actian columnar DB".